# STM32F Current sinking to I/O pin with 5V Vcc

Tags: stm32, current-sink

I'm working with Nucleo-F411RE, which has a STM32F411RET6 uC.

In the datasheet, the document says
Vin for FT or TC pins will have maximum of Vdd + 4.0.
Generally the uC uses Vdd = 3.3V then I understood the maximum value of the Vin for FT pins could be 7.3V.

**Then, could I use 5V Vcc and a LED with current sink to the uC?**
In other words, could
5V -> LED -> Resistor -> uC FT pin be possible?
Or, does the datasheet says 'just for I/O'?

I want to use the uC FT pin as a current sink for the LED.

Datasheet: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f411re.pdf
* The information is at **6.2 Section 'Absolute Maximum Ratings', which is at 60 page.**

Comment: A reference to the relevant page number of the datasheet would be handy. Also, please in future, complete your answer before you submit it to avoid having to edit it every 2 minutes.

Comment: I noticed some informations were lacking right after the upload, sorry for poor review of the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any of the pins in **Table 8. STM32F411xC/xE pin definitions** on page 38 of the datasheet that are listed as FT (or 5V tolerant pins) can have 5V applied to them as an input.

However, to drive an LED that is fed by 5V by one of these pins would be difficult. Turning the LED on wouldn't be a problem. The issue would be with turning the LED off, as the outputs still only output 3.3V. So you have a voltage across the LED still.

I would either supply the LED with 3.3V or switch it with a transistor if it really needs to be 5V (for whatever reason).

Comment: Set the pin to open-drain mode. When the port output bit is 0, it will output 0V. When the port output bit is 1, it will be floating (high impedance), no current flows through the LED. Check total and individual current limits in the datasheet.

Comment: @berendi good point. In addition to open drain mode, you need to make sure the pull-up and pull-down is disabled, AND that you only expect this to work on the FT designated pins, on a non FT pin the protection diode will conduct and the LED may still illuminate.